# swift 2.0 Xcode 7.2.1 как работает анимация

Tags: swift

нужна анимация = 10сек
        use = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(360, 300, 600,80))
        use.image = UIImage(named: "use0002.png")
        self.view.addSubview(use)

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
    self.use.frame = CGRect(x: -670, y: 300, width: 600, height: 80) }, completion: nil)
```

//будет работать 10сек - ответ неверный - работает 100сек
//Yosemate HDD = SSD
//запускается Yosemate на втором HDD(обычном жестком) = работает 10сек
//запускается на реальном устройстве = работает 10сек
//все перепробовал - что это = из-за SSD = ?
//кто- то натыкался на такое = ?
//так и приходится перелапачивать анимацию на нормальном HDD...

Comment: какая это платформа?

Comment: все перелопатил и пока не установил по чистому сиерру - ничего не помогало...самое интересное - сказывалось только на прямолинейной анимации и больше ни на чем другом вообще и ровно в 10 раз...все остальное в хсоде отрабатывало нормально...хсоде перепробовал все...  Мас мини...@Max Mikheyenko

Comment: Это Вы в симуляторе  Xcode такое получали?

Comment: Xcode 7-7.2... долго терпел, пока не ушел на Сиерру, но пришлось всю анимацию корректировать - не глядя, длительность ровно в 10 раз...бывает... @VAndrJ

Answer (score 0):

Может быть Вы не заметили одну галочку в настройках, которая как раз и замедляет в 10 раз анимацию для дебага:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это выглядит:

https://youtu.be/6JlRAL6wpVY

Comment: спасибо за внимание...вроде галочки не было...самое интересно, что на iOS 8.3 вроде было нормально... с остальными морока...ничего страшного...@VAndrJ